# Proxy web Service .net

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, web-services

i am writing a proxy web service which accepts the xml and sends it to another http service. problem is when i read the xml it always comes as null.

here is my code

```
      [WebMethod]
        public string HelloWorld(string xml)
        {

             xml= @"<env> <body>" + xml + @"</body> </env>";           
            return HttpPost("hhtp://testservice/", xml) ;
        }
```

here is my request xml

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <HelloWorld>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <xml>
            <request1>
            <value1 test="a"/>
        </request1>
</xml>
      </HelloWorld>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

if i use the Visual studio debugger and give the xml below i can see the values comming in, but using soapui to send the xml above i had i get Null as xml.

```
            <request1>
            <value1 test="a"/>
        </request1>
```

**UPDATE**
I used XMDocument instead of using string

Comment: if use <![CDATA[  it would just add that to the response as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the **XmlTextReader** object to read the disk file into the **XmlDocument** object.

You can find a code sample from the following code project url,

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/XML/csreadxml1.aspx

Hope this helps you...